# With the xproc file, how to debug/trace step-by-step in oxygen?

Tags: oxygenxml, xproc

I'm going to learn Xproc language. Does the oxygen software have the capability to debug/trace step-by-step with Xproc script? and how can do it? Thanks. My oxygen editor version is 21.0.

Or is there another IDE that does that?

Answer (score 0):

Oxygen XML editor does not have an XProc debugger. Maybe you can ask for debugging tips on the XProc users list. You probably need to start commenting out parts of it and test what every port outputs. Like this blog here: https://gist.github.com/josteinaj/7de65c722811e73a2ef7

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to tell me how you debug xproc script? I think it's incredible without debugging when writting lots of code, especially complex logic code.

Answer (score 0):

We have an issue registered to provide an xproc debugger in Oxygen, I will try to increase its priority.
Usually a complex system can be tested by breaking it into modules and testing each module individually:

- Find the smallest xml input for which the problem can be reproduced
- Apply each xslt stage sequentially to see which xslt is to blame
- Use Oxygen XML Editor’s debugger to debug that xslt
- Once each xslt produces the proper output chain them in the xproc
- If there are still problems comment out various stages in the xproc to see where the